# GetRTTAndHopCount equivalent in linux

Tags: c, sockets

I have done socket programming on windows environment and have used `GetRTTAndHopCount` windows api function to determine the whether the host exists on the network and to determine the round trip time and hop count to the destination ip address.Is there an equivalent posix API in Linux which does the same . I have go-ogled out but all i could find was to establish an socket connection using `connect` api .

**EDIT** : A Third party library called as `liboping` is available to use ping in c code.

Comment: The "ping" program would do the job... but one have to pipe-fork-exec to launch it, and then intercept its output... not too difficult, but wouldn't it be good if there were an equivalent ICMP-oriented library? +1 for the question, and +1 if someone will find the answer!

Comment: @GiuseppeGuerrini : do u mean to say that i have to call ping command from system or exec ?.

Comment: @GiuseppeGuerrini : There is a third party library named liboping using that we can use ping in c code .Here's the link http://verplant.org/liboping/

Comment: It should be noted that ping (along with others) require that it is enabled. You have to consider routers, firewalls and if the other end is switched on to disable them.

Comment: @ed heal : Yeah thats true , well in that case i will write an logic for TCP Ping .

Comment: @SanthoshPai: I agree with you, using "ping" directly is quite ugly. So +1 for your suggestion of "liboping" :-)